# PHP: serializing and unserializing string containing escaped characters

Tags: php, serialization, escaping

How do I correctly serialize and unserialize a string containing escaped characters?

Given:

```
$data = "\'test\'";
$out= serialize($data);
print_r($out); // ->  s:8:"\'test\'";
```

The problem here is, that the string length is not accepted by unserialize:

```
$out = 's:8:"\'test\'"';
var_dump(unserialize($out)); // -> bool(false)
```

But if I change the string length to 6 (ignoring the escape chars):

```
$out = 's:6:"\'test\'"';
var_dump(unserialize($out)); // -> string(6) "'test'"
```

It unserializes correctly.

What would be a good way of handling this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test cases don't match, you're wrapping the string in double quotes in your first example and single quotes in the second, causing the escape character to be taken literally in the latter.

```
$out = '\'test\'';
```

is different from

```
$data = "\'test\'";
```

if you do

```
$data = "\'test\'";
$out= serialize($data);
print_r($out); // ->  s:8:"\'test\'";
$data = unserialize($out);
print_r($data); // -> \'test\'
```

it will work.

Answer (score 6):

I would try calling `base64_encode()` before you serialize the data and then `base64_decode()` after unserializing the data.

```
$data = "\'test\'";
$out= serialize(base64_encode($data));
var_dump(base64_decode(unserialize($out))); // -> bool(false)
```

Comment: You are using serialize and base64_encode in the reverse order. And the base64_decode and unserialize are reversed too, of course.

Comment: Kar.ma is right. It has to be base64_encode(serialize($data)); since base64_encode expects a string. However after fixing this, the trick helped me out.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that your escape characters are being evaluated by PHP. If you want to keep them intact, you should escape them too :) Example:

```
$out = 's:8:"\'test\'"'; // $out = s:8:"'test'"
$out = 's:8:"\\\'test\\\'"'; // $out = s:8:"\'test\'"

var_dump(unserialize($out)); // string(8) "\'test\'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using serialize and deserialize, try `json_encode` and `json_decode`. The latter will do the (un)escaping of the quotes for you.

Comment: `serialize()` and `unserialize()` are working as good back and forth as the json functions.